# Computer randomly shuts off, and won't start until power is reset

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have been having an issue with my computer lately. The computer randomly turns off, as though someone pulled the plug, except and USB attached hardware, and motherboard remains powered on. The computer will almost always turn off within about 15 seconds of powering it on, and after that, it is completely random. (As far as I can tell)
My first thought was the power supply was faulty, but I tried temporarily connecting another one, and the same things happened. I eliminated the overheating part, as it can turn off within 5 seconds of turning on for the first time, and it shouldn't have been able to get hot at all in that time period. My next thought was that the RAM was not seated properly, but that also was not the issue.
   I am currently thinking that the motherboard is the issue, but I don't really want to spend money if I am not completely sure of what the issue is here. Any help would be great.

Here is the motherboard that I am using.
http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2758#ov

Comment: Look into the front panel IO

Comment: I already tried the front panel pins. I disconnected all of them and put a jumper pin on the power pins. It still rebooted.